# rethinkdb php rql append to nested field

Tags: php, rethinkdb

I've got an empty field called "accommodation" I try to append with an array of datas using this code:

```
r\table('xxx')->get($_POST['id'])->update(['accommodations' =>
r\row('accommodations')->append(['name' => $_POST['name'] , 'checkin' => 
$checkin , 'checkout' => $checkout , 'status' => 'rq'])])->run($conn);
```

But nothing is updated so far. I've checked about all my variables and all is fine (the ID, name, checkin and checkout dates...) and I don't have any php error as well. php rql api manual is not very specific about the way to append a nested field so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong there. Hope someone can help me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You say `accomodations` field is empty: if it's not of type array (`null` for instance), or if it doesn't exist, then the query will be rejected.
You may use a `branch` to test all cases:

```
r\table('xxx')->get($_POST['id'])->update(function($doc){
  return [
    'accomodations' => r\branch(
      // test the field does not exist or is not an array
      $doc->hasFields('accomodations')->not()->or($doc('accomodations')->typeOf()->ne('ARRAY')),
      // test true: absent or not an array --> override the value
      [
        [
          'name' => $_POST['name'],
          'checkin' => $checkin ,
          'checkout' => $checkout ,
          'status' => 'rq'
        ]
      ],
      // test false: exists as an array --> append
      $doc('accomodations')->append([
        'name' => $_POST['name'],
        'checkin' => $checkin ,
        'checkout' => $checkout ,
        'status' => 'rq'
      ])
    )
  ];
})->run($conn);
```

Not tested with PHP connector though. Hope this helps!